# how to add Image instead of Icon in card Template - Oracle Apex

Tags: oracle, oracle-apex, facet, faceted-search, oracle-apex-19.2

I have a classic report with the standard query for a card in the classic report for the search results of a faceted region but the it main focus is getting it to query from the database and showing on the card as an image instead of an icon (i.e. i want to put an image where the card icon normally is). I tried googling it and altering the template but i have found no solution.

Please note this is in Oracle Apex 19.2

[image]

The code includes

```
SELECT
    id,     
    decode(nvl(dbms_lob.getlength(LOADED_PHOTO),0),0,null,
       '<img alt="'||apex_escape.html_attribute(name)||'" title="'||apex_escape.html_attribute(name)
              ||'" style="border: 4px solid #CCC; -moz-border-radius: 50%; -webkit-border-radius: 50%;" '
              ||'src="'||apex_util.get_blob_file_src('P586_LOAD_PHOTO',id)||'" height="75" width="75" />') CARD_ICON,           
              
    'My Company' CARD_TITLE,   
    'This is my Company' CARD_TEXT,  
    'Subtext of my company' CARD_SUBTEXT
FROM  dual
```

Any help would be appreciated
Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you are not including the mimetype as the documentation says.

https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/application-express/19.1/aeapi/GET_BLOB_FILE_SRC-Function.html#GUID-21F2D33A-A616-48B5-BAF5-A85C0EDC998F

```
SELECT ID, NAME,CASE WHEN NVL(dbms_lob.getlength(document),0) = 0
THEN NULL 
ELSE CASE WHEN attach_mimetype like 'image%'
THEN '<img src="'||apex_util.get_blob_file_src('P4_DOCUMENT',id)||'" />' 
ELSE 
'<a href="'||apex_util.get_blob_file_src('P4_DOCUMENT',id)||'">Download</a>'
end 
END new_img
FROM TEST_WITH_BLOB
```

Comment: Hi that did not work @Enrique Flores, all i am gwtting is a circle in the icon display of the card

Comment: I think the documentation is right but you didn't understand what mime type is